# Converting Latex Equation to Word (file))

Tags: latex

How am I supposed to convert latex equations to a Word file? When I enter the code in https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/ it works without problems. The code would be:

```latex
{a}_{n}\enspace\underrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} \enspace0 \enspace u. \enspace{b}_{n}\enspace\underrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\enspace \infty

\\1) \enspace \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {a}_{n}*{b}_{n} = \frac{3}{n}*n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3 = 3 \enspace 2) -\frac{1}{n}*n^2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}-n=-\infty

\\ b) \enspace

{a}_{n}\enspace\underrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} \enspace\infty \enspace u. \enspace{b}_{n}\enspace\underrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\enspace \infty

\\1) \enspace \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} ({a}_{n}-{b}_{n})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n-n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}0=0 \enspace 2) \enspace (3+n)-n=lim3=3 \enspace3)\enspace n^2-n=\infty \enspace4) \enspace n-n^2 = -\infty
```

If enter this in Word (with the option Latex ofc) it does not work.

`{a}_{n}` is working for instance in Word entered as an equation with the option Latex. Same with `\infinity`. But `\enspace` isn't working. It does not convert but rather just shows "\enspace".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little program [tex2mathml](https://github.com/vertexi/tex2mathml) to convert tex form equation to word compatible mathml.

For you equations I test it by myself. Just need a little modify(remove `\\`) to the origin tex and then works fine.

[image: equation1]
[image: result]
[image]
[image]